# Dynamic string class breaking with seg fault when there is more than 1 object

Tags: c++, string, dynamic-memory-allocation

Everything works fine when there is just 1 object, but when I added another one it broke.

```
class DinString {
private:
    char *str;
    int len;
public:
    DinString() {str = NULL; len = 0;}
    DinString(const char *s) {
    strcpy(str, s);
    len = 0;
    while(str[len]) {len++;}
}

char* getString() const {return str;}
int getLen() const {return len;}
};
```

When I tried debugging it with 2 objects it broke on the first object declaration, which is even weirder, but again, with just one object works fine.

Comment: `char* getString() const {return str;}` returns a non-const pointer but the method is `const`. Someone could use the pointer returned by `getString() const` to modify a `const String`. It should return a `const char*`.

Comment: "Everything works fine when there is just 1 object" no it does not, the fact that your program does not crash is not a reason.

Answer (score -1):

Realized the problem was that I had to allocate memory for it first. I thought that `strcpy` does that for you, but apparently it doesn't.
The constructor should look like this:

```
DinString(const char *s) {
    len = 0;
    while(s[len]) len++;
    str = new char[len];
    strcpy(str, s);
}
```

Doing this makes everything work ok.

Comment: You will encounter other problems related to copy construction and copy assignment. Read about the [rule of 3/5/0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: `new char[len]` is still one byte too short. What about `strdup` and `strlen`?

Comment: You are not deleting the `char` arrays you are allocating. You will need to implement a destructor.

Comment: "I thought that strcpy does that for you" have you tried to read the documentation? Just in case.

Comment: "Doing this makes everything work ok." no it does not.

Comment: @tkausl might want to preface `strdup` usage with mention that it would require different deallocation. Very good points about `strlen` and too short allocation.